# How to show a div if keyup is empty in JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a code that show a div content that been type in search box.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() { //#myinput is the search box
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

//#myList is the content that displays the searched data.
    $("#myList .card").filter(function() { 
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

Now I want to show this div

```
<div class="alert alert-warning text-center" id="emptyList" style="display:none;">
        <strong>No data found!</strong> You can add product by clicking the button "Add item" below or <a href="addItem.php">click here</a>
</div>
```

if the filter is empty.

I am new to jquery so can you guys help me on this.

Comment: I have no issue in showing the searched item. I just want to show that div if the keyup is null

Comment: Do you realy mean keyup is null or the #myInput filed is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a check for visible cards using `:visible` pseudo selector, like :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() { //#myinput is the search box
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    //#myList is the content that display the searched data.
    $("#myList .card").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });

    if (!$("#myList .card:visible").length) {
      $('#emptyList').show();
    } else {
      $('#emptyList').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

The shorhand version could be written like:

```
$('#emptyList').toggle(!$("#myList .card:visible").length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the input field is empty or not

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() { //#myinput is the search box
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

        if(value.lenght() =< 0){
          $('div').append('
               <div class="alert alert-warning text-center" id="emptyList"  style="display:none;"><strong>No data found!</strong> You can add product by clicking the button  "Add item" below or <a href="addItem.php">click here</a></div>')
          }
     else{
          //#myList is the content that displays the searched data.
           $("#myList .card").filter(function() { 
             $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
           });
        }   
      });
   });
```